# Editar Arquivo TXT com cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-2, helper

Galera se possível gostaria de uma ajuda para editar um arquivo `.txt` que está formatado com `json_decode()`.

No controller ficou assim:

```
public function index()
{
    $json_str = file_get_contents('files/restaurante.txt','r+');
    $json_arr = json_decode($json_str);
    $this->set('json_arr', $json_arr);
}
```

Uma Linha da View:

```
<h3><?=$value->{'salada_segunda'}; ?></h3>
```

Ele busca a informação perfeitamente. Gostaria de uma ajuda para fazer uma função de edição desse arquivo via input direto do navegador, para o usuário não precisar editar diretamente no arquivo. Antes eu salvava esse dados no banco, e os meus inputs eram assim:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="input-group">
        <?=
            $this->Form->input('salada_segunda',[
                'between'     => '<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-grain"></span></span>',
                'type'        => 'text',
                'class'       => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => 'Salada',
                'required'    => false,
                'label'       => false,
                'div'         => false
            ]);
        ?>
    </div>          
</div>
```

Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas pra ficar registrado, consegui resolver o problema.
A função ficou desta forma:

```
public function edit()
{
    if($this->request->is(array('post', 'put')))
    {
        $retornoJson = json_encode($this->request->data);
        file_put_contents('files/restaurante.txt', $retornoJson);
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```